# Talend component that takes multiple rows as input and returns one row as output?

Tags: talend

I have an XML file (tFileInputXML) as the start point of my job, from that XML, i'd like to "combine" all its rows in a java List/Array/Whatever and get that List as output.

Is there a component in Talend that offers such mechanism ?

NB : I've already tried the TJavaFlex component but it still output many rows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file, map its fields using [tXMLMap](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/18.21+tXMLMap) and then process them in a java component :

[image: talend xml]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how to specify into the tXMLMap to loop through all the rows of the tfileInputXML and put them into an array for example ?

Comment: tXMLMap offer the possibility to choose which element to loop over, check the link in my answer. The java array will be created in tJavaFlex and updated in every interation.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new at Talend, I've read the link you've put but I don't get how the loop will be implemented into the tXMLMap, and how to deal with the array into tJavaFlex ?